# Break a sentence in two parts on first occurrence of a a number

Tags: php, regex, preg-split

I am in a situation that iIneed to break the line 'Havenlaan 86C Bus 12' into two parts

```
$str = 'Havenlaan 86C Bus 12'; 
$regex = '/[ ^\d]/';
$flags = PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE | PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY;
$exploded = preg_split( $regex,$str, 2, $flags);
print_r($exploded);
```

The above code sucessfully does the job and the out out is below.

1. Havenlaan
2. 86C Bus 12

BUT when I change the string to $str = 'Havenlaan ABC 86C Bus 12';

I get

```
1. Havenlaan
2. ABC 86C Bus 12
```

What I need is

```
1. Havenlaan ABC

2. 86C Bus 12
```

ie. first output should be pure string and second one should start with a number and can be followed by characters.

Comment: remove space inside brackets /[^\d]/

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use lookahead

```
$regex = '/(?=\d)/';
```

This would split at the first occurrence of a digit (with the *limit* specified as 2).

Comment: Yes this is what i was looking for. perfect.

Comment: In the mean time i created this workaround
$Streetblock='Havenlaan ABC 86C Bus 12;


$regex = '/[\d]/';
$flags = PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE | PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY;
$exploded = preg_split( $regex,$Streetblock, 2, $flags);


 $strpos=strpos($str,$exploded[1])-1;

$Street=trim($exploded[0]);
$House_Bus=trim($str[$strpos].$exploded[1]);

Answer (score 1):

If you just split twice, use `/(?=\d)/`

Answer (score 0):

`/ \d/` works as a delimiter.

`[ ^\d]` matches only a single character of either a space or `^\d` not-a-digit.